# Excel VBA yearfrac with mins and maxes

Tags: vba, excel, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to find the number of weeks between two dates in Excel VBA (with some min/max functionality in between), was getting Type Mismatch error (Run-time error '13') for the following line:

```
WeeksWorked = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown _ 
             (52 * Application.WorksheetFunction.YearFrac _ 
             (Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(DOH, DateValue("Jan 1, 2012")), _ 
              DateValue("Dec 31, 2012")), 0)
```

Anyone have any direction as to what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using Datediff()  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you could just do:

```
debug.print DateDiff("ww", DateValue("Jan 1, 2012"), DateValue("Dec 31, 2012"))
```

---

If for some reason you wanted to roll your own you could truncate the quotient of:

```
| day1 - day2 | 
---------------
       7
```

Example code:

```
Sub test_numWeeks_fn()
    Call numWeeks(DateValue("Jan 1, 2012"), DateValue("Dec 31, 2012"))
End Sub

Function numWeeks(d1 As Date, d2 As Date)
    Dim numDays As Long
    numDays = Abs(d1 - d2)
    numWeeks = Int(numDays / 7)
    Debug.Print numWeeks
End Function
```

Result:

```
52
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, decided to roll my own...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why do you need to use this in VBA, here is something you can try.

In Excel:

Assuming Start Date is in A1, End Date is in A2, then A3,

```
=(NETWORKINGDAYS(A1,A2))/5
```

Now that is in the perspective of business days, thus giving 5 day week. If you need 7 day week with regular days,

```
=WEEKNUM(A3)-WEEKNUM(A2)
```

> The function WEEKNUM() in the Analysis Toolpack addin calculates the correct week number for a given date, if you are in the U.S. The user defined function below will calculate the correct week number depending on the national language settings on your computer.

If you still need to use VBA try this: (as Tim pointed out `DateDiff` pretty handy.) Or you can even use `Evaluate to trigger WEEKNUM`.

```
Option Explicit

Function numWeeks(startDate As Date, endDate As Date)
    numWeeks = DateDiff("ww", startDate, endDate)
End Function
```

**Using Evaluate on WEEKNUM**:

```
Function numWeeks(startDate As Range, endDate As Range)
Dim s As Integer, t As Integer
    s = Application.Evaluate("=WEEKNUM(" & startDate.Address & ",1)")
    t = Application.Evaluate("=WEEKNUM(" & endDate.Address & ",1)")
    numWeeks = t - s
End Function
```

---

- [Reference for Excel VBA DataTime Functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeVBA.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, definitely helpful. I needed it in VBA for a program that determines the maximum number of weeks a population of employees worked for.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try below code :

```
Sub example()

Dim dob As Date
dob = #7/31/1986#

Dim todaydt As Date
todaydt = Date

Dim numWeek As Long
numWeek = DateDiff("ww", dob, todaydt) ' Difference in weeks

End Sub
```